# How to compare rows from the same table under a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have this sample data:

```
DATE        VALUE  ID
2010-09-28  1      20000 
2010-09-28  1      50000 X
2010-09-28  3      20001 
2010-09-28  3      50001 X
2010-10-02  6      50002
2010-10-02  6      50003
```

My problem is that I have duplicated data, and I can only differentiate them by the auto-incremented ID: the duplicate has quite a good margin of difference; I'd like to delete the latest entries, considering the date and value are equal compared to their corresponding previous entry (marked with X). It is no problem though if rows are equal, if they don't have a previous ID (as in the last 2 rows).

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use analytical function for same.

Comment: Why not one of the rows with value 6?

Comment: @tombom they do not have a previous entry, so they are not duplicate. I mean, it's no problem for rows to have the same value. I only have to check whether there's an exact same entry, but with much lower ID.

Comment: I dont get why the last two are genuine but the ones marked with X are not. Before your latest edit (which is when i posted my answer) the last 2 ids where 50002 and 59003 which would make sense (not being duplicates) because they had distant ids. But now it just doesnt make any sense. Please explain.

Comment: _if they don't have a previous ID_ whose records have previous ID(valid records)?

Comment: Edited my answer according to your edits. I added an SQL Fiddle link that demonstrates it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table the ones with the X do not have the same Value... I ´ll suppose that this is a mistake.

Anyway if you want to delete duplicates when the difference between the IDs is (for example 1) you could do this.

**EDIT**: I think I get what you want now. So you don't consider as duplicates records that have succesive Ids (which is what I thought in the beggining) but you consider duplicates records who have a large difference. **So lets say the maximum difference between IDs so you won't consider them duplicates = X**

```
Delete From Table where ID IN 
(Select a.ID from Table a, Table b Where a.ID-b.ID > X
AND a.Date = b.Date and a.Value = b.Value)
```

In your example if you put 1 or larger in place of X it will do the job that you want.

[SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE OF THE SELECTION USED TO DELETE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39649/1/0)

You will see above that with the selection i've given you, you get the Ids you want to delete.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer.. the value has to be equal to the corresponding "low ID row".

Comment: I see so you want the exact opposite of my answer. hehe
So what is a big margin to you. I mean what is the minimum difference of IDs that you would consider a duplicate.